# Is my time-complexity paranoia in this case justified?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) for an `unordered_set` says that *'Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time complexity.'*  In the worst case, all of them degenerate to be linear in time.  As against this, in case of a `set`, [it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) says all the operations are *Logarithmic in the size of the container* (which IMHO alludes to a worse case scenario as well).

So, given a problem, how do I determine whether to use a `set` or an `unordered_set` (I only need efficient inserts, lookups and removals - their order does not make any difference).  I think, unless I want the elements to be sorted, it makes sense to always use a `set` over an `unordered_set` since I wouldn't know when the problem has gone over to become a worst case (and no longer an average case).  Similarly, I have the same question in case of an `unordered_map` and a `map` as well.

Edit: I am asking this question mostly from an interview (and to some extent, a competitive programming) perspective.

Comment: I would recommend not getting too hung up on complexity bounds of algorithms, if you care how fast a program runs in practice. Learn profiling and measurement well instead (and probably hardware).

Comment: Worst-case performance is linear because when every element gets the same hash the structure degenerates to a simple list. This will almost never happen unless you specifally design a hash to be that bad.

Comment: `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` implement completely different data structures. A lot of factors determine which one is better, such as speed of comparisons, speed of hashing, and whether someone is designing malicious input to try to exploit your program. Understand how the data structures work and benchmark to figure out which one will be faster in your specific case.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann It is also possible that the input is designed to cause a bunch of hash collisions, which can be the case in an [algorithmic complexity attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_complexity_attack).

Comment: Just a little anectode: Linear search can be alot faster than a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` when youre only dealing with 30 elements or so.

Comment: Also relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2fKMP47slQ

Comment: `std::unordered_set` has slow speed in worst case but the chances that it is non-constant time are ridiculously insignificant. Not something that can happen in practice.

Comment: @ALX23z, so would you agree that for all intents and purposes in general programming, it makes sense to use an `unordered_set` over a `set` (unless we want things to be sorted)?

Comment: @ALX23z It can happen if a malicious person is designing inputs to cause hash collisions.

Comment: @J.Doe Theres no definite answer to this. Alot of factors completely irrelevant to the theoretical data structure (cache lines would be the premier example) affect actual performance and the answer you will always get is: if its really that important to you, measure and compare it. But even then it already really important how/what you measure. Is your structure always in cache? What operations do you perform? What data is inside it?

Comment: Hashing `String`s in early Java could get pretty bad. All you needed to do was use a consistent prefix and everything went to smurf. Nothing malicious here, just a poor choice in the `String` hasher.

Comment: @BessieTheCow for malicious-user-case consider generating randomized hash functions.

Comment: @ALX23z I know there are techniques to mitigate such attacks. It's just something that people have to keep in mind.

Comment: Although the implementation is not dictated by the standard, `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`, are just conventional hash table algorithms.  In the unlucky, unlikely, and extreme case that all your items hash to the same the same value, the data structure degrades into a singly linked list.  In this case the lookup time goes from `O(1)` to `O(N)`.

Comment: And again, although not dictated by the standard, the `set` and `map` are implemented as binary trees.  The container relies a bit less on the hash of the item and more on the implementation of the `<` operator for each item.   Hence, `O(lg N)` is a bit easier to guarantee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think, unless I want the elements to be sorted, it makes sense to always use a set over an unordered_set

If you want elements sorted, then you cannot choose unordered set. If the order does not matter, then either may be an option.

It mostly boils down to whether you care about worst case or average case performance. In many cases, you don't even need to know which you care about since you can simply measure which is faster for your program, and make the choice based on that.

An exception is the case of real time constraints, especially if they are hard. In which case you must consider worst case complexity to make sure that the constraints are never exceeded.